# Positioning HTML using CSS

Tags: html, css

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mugman/kw7nyobq/)

I am still having difficulty with the positioning HTML elements using CSS. I understand the basics, that elements are displayed primarily as block or inline; however, when it comes down to actually coding a site I get confused. I have include my HTML coding below, which I am mostly happy with. I have now moved on to styling the code with CSS. I would like to create a Navigational bar, at the top of my page; to do so, I have used the CSS coding (also below).

Firstly, I displayed my list as inline-block. Secondly, I have floated my heading to the left and my list to the right, which all looks fine. My confusion comes as to why my  class ’slider’ then moves up in between the two elements?

I would very much appreciate a solution, but even more so, I would really appreciate if you could explain the actual theory an functionality as to why this is occurring. My own theory is that by floating the two elements, they have been removed from the ’normal’ flow of the page, allowing the next element on the page to move into the empty space left behind?  Again, I would appreciate a solution, but more so I would like to understand for myself the theory behind it, so I can tackle similar problems in the future on my own.

```
<style>
.nav li {
   display: inline-block;
  }

.nav ul {
   float: right;
  }

.nav h1 {
   float: left;
  } 

</style>

    <div class="nav">
            <h1>Resume</h1>
        <ul>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>Portfolio</li>
            <li>Skills</li>
            <li>Experience</li>
            <li>Contact</li>
        </ul>
       </div>
    </div>


    <div class="slider">
        <h2>Andrew Hardiman</h2>
        <p>Webdesigner & Developer</p>
        <p>Read More</p>
        <p>HTML</P>
        <p>css</P>
        <h3>I design and develop amazing websites that are sleek, easy-to-navigate and exiting to use.</h3>
        <p>Work with us to plan your digital marketing mix and achieve better results online.</p>
       </div>
    </div>



    <div class="Portfolio">
       <div class="container">
        <h3>Portfolio</h3>
        <img src="https://download.unsplash.com/photo-1423655156442-ccc11daa4e99">
        <h3>Client</h3>
        <h4>JPMorgan</h4>
        <h3>Role in Project</h3>
        <h4>Project Lead</h4>
        <h3>Project Included</h3>
        <h4>Mobile and Web Interface</h4>
       </div>
    </div>


    <div class="skills">
       <div class="container">
        <h3>Skills</h3>
        <p>I am a bit of a hybrid Web Developer and like to utilise my skills both front and back end as well
        as keep in touch with my creative side designing websites</p>
        <p>html</P>
        <p>CSS</p>
        <p>JavaScript</p>
        <p>jQuery</P>
       </div>
    </div>


    <div class="Experience">
       <div class="container">
        <h3>Experience</h3>
        <h4>Work Experience</h4>
        <p>Blah blah blah, professional with this and that<p>
        <h5>Royal National Lifeboat Institution</h5>
        <p>Coastal Support Officer, blah blah blah<p>
        <h5>Pioneer Business Systems</h5>
        <p>blah d, blah d, blah</p>
        <h5>JPMorgan Chase</h5>
        <p>Some more blah d, blah</p>
       </div>
    </div>


    <div class="wrap">
       <div class="container">
        <img src="https://download.unsplash.com/photo-1424296308064-1eead03d1ad9">
        <h3>Andrew Hardiman</h3>
        <p>I have worked for one of the top Investment Banks in the world (JPMorgan) and loved
        every minute of it!</p>
        <p>Today, I have left the world of high-finance to fulfil my curiosity in the freelance
        arena which has been amazing so far and I can't think of why I did not taken the plunge sooner</p>
       </div>
    </div>


    <div class="contact">
       <div class="container">
        <div id="Username"></div>
        <div id="Email"></div>
        <div id="Cost or your project"></div>
        <div id="Timeline"></div>

        <h4>LOCATION</h4>
        <p>Flat 1, 29 Markham Road, Bournemouth, BH9 1HZ</p>

        <h4>I AM SOCIAL</h4>
            <ul>    
            <li>Facebook</li>
            <li>Twitter</li>
            <li>Google+</li>
            <li>Linkedin</li>
            <li>Flickr</li>
            </ul>

        <div class="Send>   
            <a href="#">Send</a>
        </div>

       </div>
    </div>


    <div class="location">
    </div>


    <div class="top-footer">

       <div class="footer-menu">
        <h4>Menu</h4>
        <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Portfolio</li>
        <li>Skills</li>
        <li>Experience</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
        </UL>   
       </div>


       <div class="footer-archives">
        <h4>Archives</h4>
        <ul>
        <li>March 2014</li>
        <li>April 2014</li>
        <li>May 2014</li>
        <li>June 2014</li>
        <li>July</li>
        </ul>
       </div>


       <div class="widget">
        <p>Not really sure what this is for, you'll need to find out</p>
       </div>


       <div class="follows">
        <h4>Follows</h4>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="#"></li>
        <li><a href="#"></li>
        <li><a href="#"></li>
        <ul>
       </div>



    <div class="footer-bottom">
        <P>© 2015 Website by Andrew Hardiman</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: go read http://alistapart.com/article/css-positioning-101

Answer (score 1):

You need to **clear your float** so it does not affect any following divs. Add this to your css file.

```
.slider{
    clear:both;
}
```

When you float an elements, left or to the right, it creates empty space which allows other element to take up those space. Clearing the float will prevent these element to take up this empty space.

Or you can fix the affecting element

```
.nav{
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/0r4vvj9L/6/)

Comment: Works as well, but with this approach this behaviour this will occur again on another page (where's there's no slider). Best thing is to fix the troubling div itself instead of the ones surrounding it.

Answer (score 1):

### Solution 1:

You can simply clear your slider like so:

```
.slider{
    clear:both;
}
```

**But to answer your question** as to why your `.slider` went between your `ul` and your `h1`. Since the width of the two elements you had `floated` weren't taking up 100% of the width of the parent container, your `.slider` had enough room to flow between them. That's why adding `clear:both` to your `.slider` class was necessary.

### [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kw7nyobq/1/)

---

### Solution 2:

**Something to consider.** Since you aren't paying by the `div`, you can use them liberally as containers. Set their width to 100% and add your elements inside. You could easily do something like this to solve your problem.

```
<div class="row">
    <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Portfolio</li>
        <li>Skills</li>
        <li>Experience</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Then give .row these styles:

```
.row {
    display: inline-block; /* or display: block;* display: table; */
    width:100%;
    clear:both;
}
```

This will ensure that no other elements enter this space.

**Here's a fiddle with this solution:**

### [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kw7nyobq/3/)

---

**Addressing concerns in comments:**

Please read [this article](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/) from CSS-Tricks

```
div {
  display: inline;        /* Default of all elements, unless UA stylesheet overrides */
  display: inline-block;  /* Characteristics of block, but sits on a line */
  display: block;         /* UA stylesheet makes things like <div> and <section> block */
  display: run-in;        /* Not particularly well supported or common */
  display: none;          /* Hide */
}
```

> There is a whole set of display values the force non-table elements to
>   behave like table-elements, if you need that to happen. -css-tricks

```
div {
  display: table;
  display: table-cell;
  display: table-column;
  display: table-colgroup;
  display: table-header-group;
  display: table-row-group;
  display: table-footer-group;
  display: table-row;
  display: table-caption;
}
```

Comment: Same comment as I gave to Nakib: it's not a consistent approach. It will occur again on other pages which don't have a slider. Better fix the misbehaving element itself.

Comment: @cptstarling he asked for theory as to why it happened, besides I offered two solutions.

Comment: Which is ok, so did I btw. But I don't think this is a waterproof solution. If my comment sounded harsh, then this was absolutely not my intention, I'm only discussing it with you :)

Comment: Thank you Dan, this seems to make sense to me. However, I have added it to my coding and it does not seem to have made any difference? Any idea why this could be? https://jsfiddle.net/mugman/kw7nyobq/

Comment: Have you checked out my updated fiddle?: https://jsfiddle.net/kw7nyobq/3/  Also, are you working exclusively in a jsfiddle or do you have a site up? You may need to clear your browser cache by pressing Ctrl+F5

Comment: It's not working for me, am I missing something obvious? https://jsfiddle.net/mugman/0r4vvj9L/

Comment: I think you just need to hit run or update on your jsfiddle, it's not real-time so you have to click "Run" after you make a change. Check out your jsFiddle links your adding in your comments above, they're identical to your initial. I don't think your updating your fiddle.

Comment: Definitely updating fiddle!

Comment: This solution is definitely not working for me!! I must be doing something wrong, but I just cannot see what? Any thoughts? https://jsfiddle.net/mugman/0r4vvj9L/3/

Comment: change your display from block to table, that worked for me in your fiddle **display:table;**

Comment: I've also tried your solution here http://htmledit.squarefree.com/ , it just doesn't work. Also, why table and not block, the solution seems a little haphazard when we are having to shoe-horn certain parts for others.

Comment: I've adapted this "haphazard" method from bootstrap which was developed by twitter. Display: table; isn't hacky at all, it's supported by every browser http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-table

Comment: I appreciate that Dan, but what I mean is, I no better understand what is happening here than when I started, not really. The solution you suggest was to create a container class and give that container a width of 100%, therefore preventing further elements from overflowing into this container. This has not worked, so you have adapted the solution using the display: table function, which in itself is not 'hacky', but you've adopted it in a hacky way to your own solution.

Comment: Updated my post to address some of your concerns. Sorry you couldn't get my solution working, I've proved that it does work by sending you multiple working jsfiddles.

Answer (score 1):

**Quick answer:**
Like everyone else has mentioned, you need to clear your floats.

```
.nav { 
clear: both; 
overflow: auto; }
```

You can see it in action in a [fork of your jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/htmlmonkey/m1rkxhnt/). (P.S. you had a few syntax errors in your HTML that I fixed in the above linked fork. Mostly closing tags missing or missing the /.)

**More explanation:**
You have 2 children inside of DIV.nav, and both of them are floating, but because those elements don't fill the entire space, whatever is below DIV.nav starts creaping up to fill any gaps.

I'd also highly recommend checking out beginner articles on sites like [SitePoint](http://www.sitepoint.com/html-css-beginners-guide/) or [A List Apart](http://alistapart.com/article/alaprimer2).
Hope that helps a little.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS:

```
.nav{
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

This will prevent this container (`.nav`) from collapsing, which is what it does (add a background or border to see it in effect). I reckon that these menu items don't expland in a fly-out, so this `overflow: hidden` won't obstruct anything.

In case it does have a fly-out, consider adding an extra div below both children (`h1`, `ul`). Adding `clear: both` to that div underneath should have the same effect.

If the container contains nothing but floating elements, collapsing may occur, as in this case.