# HTML CSS positioning

Tags: html, css

```css
.container {width: 100%;}
.nav h1 {float: left;}
.nav ul {float: right;}
.nav li {display: inline-block;}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>.nav h1 Resume</h1>
    <ul>
      <li>.nav ul .nav li Home ul li</li>
      <li>Portfolio ul li</li>
      <li>Skills ul li</li>
      <li>Experience ul li</li>
      <li>Contact ul li</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="slider">
  <h2>div.slider h2 Text Testingx</h2>
  <p>Web designer & Developement</p>
  <p>Read less DO more</p>
  <p>HTML</p>
  <p>css</p>
  <h3>I design and develop amazing websites that are sleek,
        easy-to-navigate and exiting to use.</h3>
  <p>Work with us to plan your digital marketing mix and achieve better results online.</p>
</div>
```

**this is clearly a different question. The first was asking how to remove the overlap. Here, I am asking why after giving a width of 100% to an element, it still allows other elements to enter its space; this was not even remotely approached on the last question**

I do not wish for a solution but rather a detailed explanation, so I can understand what is happening for myself and be better educated to resolve issues for myself in the future; I'm just trying to learn the theory, this is not a live project as such.

I do not understand what is happening here. I am trying to create a navigational bar but my `div class="slider"` keeps imposing on my `div class="nav"`. In order to resolve this, I have created a container class for my "`nav`" elements, and give this 100% of the width. My understanding, was that by giving these elements 100% of the width there would be no 'free' space for anything else to enter. This is obviously not the case, would somebody be kind enough to explain why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Positioning HTML using CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30810173/positioning-html-using-css)

Comment: Not helpful Nakib, and incorrect. I am trying to ask this question in response to a query that was raised off the back OF the last question. Which is, when giving an element 100% width, how is it that other elements still overlap into its space. This cannot possibly be a duplicate of the first question, as it is derived from the ANSWER to the first question!

Comment: Do you think UpperCase is needed?

Comment: I think strong words are needed but I refrained.

Comment: @pnuts Would have been cool if you have fixed the title too.

Comment: @pnuts Well I'd rather fix the entire question rather than a simple retag. Not going to do it again as all of your retagging is pushing these old questions to the front page.

Comment: @pnuts There's more than just you and I on SO, perhaps you shouldn't be mass-editing tags? Also, it's showing up in [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/27129496#27129496).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have used `float:left` and `float:right`....that's why the `nav h1`and `nav ul` is out of document flow it mean other element will not consider them(as they don't exist). so the height of `nav` is 0 that's why the slider div is going up.

if you want solution read about css clear property

Comment: THANK YOU TARUN! What is with the attitude on this site!! That is all I wanted, a simple explanation. Thank you. Why the need to mark you down negatively because you said Hi and Thank You on your message, ridiculous.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {width: 100%;}
.nav h1 {float: left;}
.nav ul {float: right;}
.nav li {display: inline-block;}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>.nav h1 Resume</h1>
    <ul>
      <li>.nav ul .nav li Home ul li</li>
      <li>Portfolio ul li</li>
      <li>Skills ul li</li>
      <li>Experience ul li</li>
      <li>Contact ul li</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="slider">
  <h2>div.slider h2 Text Testingx</h2>
  <p>Web designer & Developement</p>
  <p>Read less DO more</p>
  <p>HTML</p>
  <p>css</p>
  <h3>I design and develop amazing websites that are sleek,
        easy-to-navigate and exiting to use.</h3>
  <p>Work with us to plan your digital marketing mix and achieve better results online.</p>
</div>
```